# Where's the auto-replace function of the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, text-input

I've looked in the whole parameters of my Nexus 5 (Lollipop 5.1) and I can't find the way to customize the auto-replace function.

What I want to do is simple, I want some abbreviation like `asap` to be automatically changed for `as soon as possible`, or `swag` to be replaced by `NEVER USE THIS WORD MORON`

Answer (score 6):

This functionality is covered by the operation of the Personal Dictionary. Settings > Language and input > Google Keyboard > Text correction > Personal Dictionary. Select the language to which you would like to make the addition.

Finally, the '+ Add' button allows you to define a word or phrase, and, optionally a shortcut.

So for your example, Word = 'As soon as possible', shortcut = asap.

Comment: It  doesn't work!

Comment: You may have to install the Google Keyboard or Gboard from the Play Store if you don't see it in “Language and input”.

Comment: It works for me, it was just moved, in the current version, it's directly to the main *Settings* menu, just open the *Settings* > *Dictionary* > *Personal dictionary*, choose if you want to define it for all languages or just a specific one and there, you can add words or phrases and their shortcuts.

Comment: What @prab2112 said: It doesn't work.  It doesn't replace anything.  At most, it shows a "possible correction" after you type.  But if you want it to replace the illiterate constructions `i` or `u` or `U` (which apparently are in its dictionary!) with `I` or `you`, it doesn't work for that.

Answer (score 1):

April 2017
This works in Note5, Android 7.
Settings 
Language & Input
Virtual Keyboard 
Samsung Keyboard 
Predictive Text (click on predictive text)
Text Shortcut

Hope this'll help you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

download thumb keyboard from playstore.
link  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beansoft.keyboardplus
 in keyboard settings go to text substitution and add  words of your choice.
I am using this keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

On my phone, you go to Virtual Keyboard, not Google Keyboard, then to Gboard > Personal Dictionary > English > then click the + symbol in the top right.